# Issues in cuda toolkit installation

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I'm trying to set up cuda toolkit but even if i've already installed visual studio express 2013, cuda toolkit installation warn me that it can't find any visual studio installation.

I'm wondering if it is the 2013 express version that could raise an error ?

Furthermore I would like to code and compile by hand, when I do so I get this error : "nvcc fatal error no cl.exe found"

Thus I put the flag -ccbin"path/to/my/gcc" but I get an error that told me there isn't any supported version of visual studio.

May I understand that it isn't possible to compile by hand without visual studio ?

Comment: which CUDA version did you install?

Comment: I installed cuda 7.5

Comment: while [CUDA 6.5](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Windows.pdf) lists VS2013 Express as supported, [CUDA 7](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Getting_Started_Windows.pdf) does not anymore. Maybe you should try the listed "Visual Studio Community 2013" edition instead?

Comment: I just installed it so you are telling me that cuda 7.5 would work with vs2013 community ? I'm going to try now by uninstall and install cuda 7.5 again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed visual studio community 2013 and it seems, finally, that it worked.